# CSS: How do I get wrapped labels to align

Tags: html, css

I've got some radio buttons which I'm formatting to look a little prettier than the standard CSS.  When the text associated with the radio button is longer it wraps underneath the radio button and you cannot see some of the text.  How do I get the text to wrap and align?

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #eee;
}

form {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
    margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-indent: 3.25em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 2.5em;
    background: #D1D3D4;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
    color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: #9CE2AE;
    background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
    color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-indent: 3.25em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 2.5em;
    background: #D1D3D4;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
    content:'✓';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
    color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
    content:'✓';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: #80ffff;
    background-color: #0080c0;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
    color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
    <label for="radio1">First Option</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
    <label for="radio2">Second Option</label>
</div>

<div>   
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
    <label for="radio3">Third Option</label>
</div>

<div>   
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" class="radio"/>
    <label for="radio4">Fourth Option is longer</label>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HenryM/gb8snazq/) with my CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change some css like

```
label {
    border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block; /* add this property */
    padding-left: 50px; /* add this property */
    width: 200px;
}
input.radio:empty ~ label {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    /*text-indent: 3.25em; - remove this property*/
    margin-top: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gb8snazq/4/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `text-indent` and use `padding-left`.

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
 background-color: #eee;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 padding-left: 3em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 1em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'✓';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'✓';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #80ffff;
 background-color: #0080c0;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
<label for="radio1">First Option</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio2">Second Option</label>
</div>

<div> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio3">Third Option</label>
</div>

<div> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio4">Fourth Option is longer</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 10px;
color: #999;
background-color: #eee;
}

form {
margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
clear: both;
margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  width: 145px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

/* hide input */
input.radio:empty {
margin-left: -999px;
}

/* style label */
input.radio:empty ~ label {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-top: 2em;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 55px;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
content: '';
width: 2.5em;
background: #D1D3D4;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
line-height: 2.5em;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
content:'\2714';
text-indent: .9em;
color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
content:'\2714';
text-indent: .9em;
color: #9CE2AE;
background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
line-height: 2.5em;
text-indent: 3.25em;
margin-top: 1em;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
content: '';
width: 2.5em;
background: #D1D3D4;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* toggle hover */
input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
content:'✓';
text-indent: .9em;
color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
color: #888;
}

/* toggle on */
input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
content:'✓';
text-indent: .9em;
color: #80ffff;
background-color: #0080c0;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
color: #777;
}

/* radio focus */
input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
<label for="radio1">First Option</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio2">Second Option</label>
</div>

<div> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio3">Third Option</label>
</div>

<div> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio4">Fourth Option is longer</label>
</div>
```

- Used `padding` instead of `text-indent`
- `line-height` added to `:before`  only

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/gb8snazq/5/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input.radio:empty ~ label:before{
      content: '✓';
      color: #fff;
}

.input.radio:empty ~ label{
     text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!-- You need to add some css -->
```

[Look like this style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsVNp.png)

Comment: this isn't quite doing what I want.  It is adjusting the size of the label boxes but it the labels are very long such that they exceed the screen width it will still wrap below the checkbox.